# eb cli doesn't apply configs via config files

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I try to create elastic beanstalk environment with application load balancer, all config should be at config files, but config from files doesn't apply

I created config file 01_environment.config with the following contents:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:
    LoadBalancerType: application
  aws:autoscaling:asg:
    MinSize: 1
    MaxSize: 3
```

but beanstalk doesn't apply this config. It can create an environment with a "Load balancer type" field with the value "classic" and therefore it create classic load balancer. But sometimes without any config files changes it create environment with a "Load balancer type application" and create classic load balancer. BUT sometimes WITHOUT any config files changes it create environment with a "Load balancer type" field with the value "application" and create APPLICATION load balancer... I don't understand what it depends on.  [In the screenshot 3 load balancers created by beanstalk with alone configuration (1 classic and 2 application), but all environments have Load balancer type application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO6hq.png)